# Можно ли в С++ поменять значения переменных за одну команду?

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Пока я думаю что это можно сделать только так:

```
T temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

Получаеться выходит 3 команды, можно ли укоротить данную операцию?

Comment: за одну инструкцию языка т.е.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::swap(a, b);
```

Но вы должны понимать, что компилятор эту операцию в любом виде и записи будет делать за несколько операций. Копированием ли, хором или ещё чем-нибудь.

Answer (score 5):

для этого существует прямая инструкция процессора xchg. никаких временных переменных. и никакой иной способ не будет работать быстрей ;)
но есть одна оговорка: размеры операндов должны быть меньше, или ровняться размеру регистра CPU. для 32ух битных машин это 4 байта, для 64ех - 8. или указатели.
т.е. для обмена целых и указателей это наилучший способ. но не для обмена структур/объектов.
и, как следствие, наилучшим решением является обменивать ссылки.

GNU assembler test: http://liveworkspace.org/code/b9a82c898c65609748ea3585dda111d9

естественно, операция атомарна. никаких "Interlocked API" не нужно ;)

Answer (score 3):

a ^= b ^= a ^= b ;)

Comment: а можно пояснить как это работает?

Comment: Расставьте скобки и учтите, что a^=b возвращает новое значение a как результат операции.
Т.е. a = b = c; эквивалентно a = (b = c); и эквивалентно b = c, a = c; т.е. результат b = c, a = c;

Comment: Получается,
<pre>a = b ^ a ^ b ^ a ^ b;
b = b ^ a ^ b;</pre>
Вспоминаем, что b ^ b можно убрать без проблем :-) и получаем искомое

Comment: Не забываем, что это актуально для целочисленных POD типов, а так же для классов у которых будет реализован оператор XOR.

Answer (score 0):

можно, если создать специальную функцию

Comment: А еще можно сделать шаблон или использовать макрос.

Comment: а шаблон это не функция?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем по теме вопроса, но если не нужен кросс-платформенный код, можно использовать расширения языков под целевые платформы. Например, для Windows - Interlocked API.

Берем функцию InterlockedExchange:

```
LONG __cdecl InterlockedExchange(
  __inout  LONG volatile *Target,
  __in     LONG Value
);
```

и две переменные first и second:

```
second = InterlockedExchange(&first, second);
```

В результате переменные first и second поменяются значениями, плюс операция атомарная для других Interlocked API функций.

Answer (score 0):

Не можно поменять значение переменных за одну команду